# How to send data to the server with an image?

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a form that captures user data and profile picture, I program this in jquery ui (modal form) and sending jquery ajax post, on the server side (PHP5.2) need to get the value of the variable $ _File and the other values ​​of the username, email, password, well my problem is in the delivery of data and image.
I hope you have understood me and I can help

Code HTML

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
                <p class="validateTips">
                    All form fields are required.</p>
                <form id="formulario">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="name">
                            Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label for="email">
                            Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label for="password">
                            Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

                    </fieldset>
                    <div id="content-image-user">
                        <div id="imageuser"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-widget"><label for="photo">Photo: </label><input type="file" name="photo" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

CODE JS

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 620,
    width: 480,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
            //allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
            var info = $("#formulario").serialize();//
            //Here!!
            // How data gathering more data in the image?
            console.log(info);
            $.post("AddUser.php", info, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#grid-data').load("GridData.php", function() {
                    //console.log('load data OK');
                });
            });
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        //allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});
```

regards
thanks
MauricioHz
Santiago, Chile

Comment: Ajax cannot do file uploads. The standard workaround is to clone your form into a hidden iframe and do a conventional POSt-based upload there: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: You can't upload files via AJAX.  You need to use an iFrame, Flash, or the xmlhttprequest2

Comment: Post your `AddUser.php` code so we can see what the PHP that is processing the AJAX request does.  Also, you can just upload the image to the server and then send the link in the AJAX request.  Otherwise you would be storing the image in the database as binary rather than filesystem.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could get a good result with jquery form pluggins,
http://hayageek.com/ajax-file-upload-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var info = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]); 
$.ajax({
  url: "AddUser.php",
  data: info,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#grid-data').load("GridData.php", function() {
      //console.log('load data OK');
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's sad to tell you that Ajax can't upload the file for javascript can't handle local file.

usually, there are 3 ways.

1.base64encode the image content, then you get the base64encoded string. post the string to the server . the server get the image content by decode the string

1. use flash upload the file . js and flash interact to implement file upload.
2. use iframe. javascript handle the html dom dynamic, trigger the submit event, then you can get the otected-stream.